# PHP: globals in function with inner function

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I am working on code that generates combinations of numbers - the code itself works well, but when I create a function from it then it does not work due to some global variables issue (maybe it has something to do with globals in inner function?):

```
$test_array=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);

function test_function($test_array){
    $generatormyArray=$test_array;

    $generatorchoose=5;
    $generatorresult = array(); 
    $generatorcombination = array();

    global $generatorresult, $generatorcombination;

    $generatorn = count($generatormyArray);

    function inner ($generatorstart, $generatorchoose_, $generatorarr, $generatorn) {
        global $generatorresult, $generatorcombination;
        if ($generatorchoose_ == 0) {
            array_push($generatorresult,$generatorcombination);
        }
        else 
            for ($generatori = $generatorstart; $generatori <= $generatorn - $generatorchoose_; ++$generatori) {
               array_push($generatorcombination, $generatorarr[$generatori]);
               inner($generatori + 1, $generatorchoose_ - 1, $generatorarr, $generatorn);
               array_pop($generatorcombination);
            }
    }

    inner(0, $generatorchoose, $generatormyArray, $generatorn);

    $output_array=array();
    foreach ($generatorresult as $one_result){
        sort($one_result);
        $one_result=implode("-",$one_result);
        array_push($output_array,$one_result);
    }
    return $output_array;
}

print_r (test_function($test_array));
```

I get this:

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

on line 20 and on all other lines with array_push() or array_pop()

Comment: `global $generatorresult, $generatorcombination;` should be at the beginning of your function, before you assign values to them. Also please indent your code properly, this is really hard to read.

Comment: Jeto: Oh, I am blind... Thank you!

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.